# Illustrator CS6 How to get my text box to scale upwards when a new line is added?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, cs6

I am using a point type text box (one that scales horizontally and vertically) but when I add a new line it expands the text box downwards. Is there was a way to get it to jump up when a new line is added keeping the bottom of the box at the same level?

Also, if there is a method of making the text box horizontally fixed but vertically relative that would be appreciated (I can't find this in the forums either).

Comment: Hey Martin, welcome to GraphicDesign. Please keep questions limited to only one question per post. If you want, you can create [a new post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with the other question

Answer (score 1):

**First question**

You can do this in Indesign, setting alignment to top, middle or bottom using Object Styles. I'm not 100%, but I don't think it's available in Illustrator.

**Second question**

When working with text in Illustrator use Area type text. Here is a little trick I use: I constantly switch between point and and Area type. (Menus - Type - Convert to X type) I use it so much I have the toggle for it as a hotkey on <kbd>F6</kbd>. Start by creating a textbox and enter your text. Then convert to Area and resize the textbox and place it where you want it. Afterwards, you can convert to Point and scale the entire text without the text changing lines and 'overflowing' as it would if you only increased font size using Area type. Remember to scale proportionally using Point type so you don't get stretched text. If you need to add more text, jump back to Area type and your text will stay inside your box. Hope that helps.

Comment: The user is asking about CS6. In CS6 there is no "Convert to Point Type / Area Type" in the Type menu https://imgur.com/gallery/Ux4hlZg